# .net/powershell regex single match

Tags: regex, powershell, .net, multiple-matches

I have spent days trying to work this out. Managed to get text to be captured but I need only one of the lines. 
I have tried various ways but always get all matches returned to me.

This line of text appears 3 times

```
<![LOG[Property SerialNumber is now = serial]LOG]!>
```

using the Regex

```
 (?<=Property\sSerialNumber\sis\snow\s\=\s)[^<]+(?=]LOG]!>)
```

I get three matches of the word serial. I only need 1.

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: what text did you tried it on? can you give a sample text?

Comment: Some more context would be helpful.  Why do you only want to match one of them?  Are you checking for the presence of a string?  Is your line of text repeated 3 times on separate lines or is it all together on one line?

Answer (score 1):

If that exact line appears three times, then [`[Regex]::Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w) will return all three of them, of course.

You can use [`[Regex]::Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz) if you're only interested in the first.